# Making a function to take inputs and give an output

Tags: macros, minipage

I am trying to make a function in order to have an image on the left and text on the right. I have come up with the following:

```
% Special container for image on left and text on right
\renewcommand\imtxt[3]{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{#1} %First argument
    \includegraphics{#2} %Second argument
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.50\linewidth}
#3 %Third Argument
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
```

I want to use this function then in my LaTeX document like so:

```
\imtxt[2cm][Images/Icon_Test.png][test text]
```

So overall, it will add an image on the left which will be 2cm wide then spacing using \quad and finally my text.

However, the \newcommand has some problems and it doesn't compile. Thoughts?

EDIT:

Example code:

```
 % Default Template and Font Size
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mwe}
 % Set Margins of the Document
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0in,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=3.8cm,bottom=2.5cm,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

% Special container for image on left and text on right
\renewcommand\imtxt[3]{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{#1}
    \includegraphics{#2}
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.50\linewidth}
#3
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

% Document begins here
\begin{document}
\imtxt{2cm}{example-image-b}{test text}
\end{document}
```

Although from suggestion to use {} instead of [] it now works, I still get warning command \imtxt undefined in Overleaf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete but small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which begins wtih `\documentclass{...}` and end with `end@document}`

Comment: you have used `\renewcommand` not `\newcommand` so it will give an error if not already defined. But if you want help with an error please always provide a test code that produces the error and show exactly the error that you get copied from the log file.

Comment: also you have defined your command with three arguments so `{}{}{}` not `[][][]`

Comment: Thanks all. I have included working example now. {} instead of [] fixed it but still have a rouge warning although PDF does output

Comment: Your image is much larger than the minipage you put it in.  Use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}` to avoid the warning.  Minipage redefines the width internally.